# What do you call someone who builds fences

Tags: word-choice, terminology, vocabulary, epithet-requests, professions

What do you call someone who builds fences other than maybe "fence builder"?

Is there a specialized name for that - maybe even archaic?

Example:
A <strike>smithy</strike> smith works with metal (Correction  [@Chris H](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/48571/chris-h))
A cooper builds barrels
A wheelwright makes wagon wheels

Comment: A smith works with metal in a smithy.

Comment: A *barrierier*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an occupation, the common terms are:

- fence builder
- fence erector
- fence installer

They are also mentioned under *construction trades* in "1990 Census of Population and Housing: Classified Index of Industries and Occupations" by *U.S Department of Commerce*:

[image]

Other related occupations that are mentioned:

- concrete fence builder
- wire-fence builder
- wire-fence erector
- wood-fence installer
- rustic-fence builder

For example, *fence erector* and *fence builder* are both mentioned in a job opening in [Canada Job Bank](http://www.jobbank.gc.ca/home-eng.do?lang=eng):

[image]

*[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/69220?rskey=YHNqtu&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)* lists *fencer* also for this sense and gives the earliest reference from 1881:

> Chiefly *Austral.* and *N.Z.* One employed in putting up fences.
>
> 1881   R. C. Praed *Policy & Passion* I. 241   ‘Where is father?’..‘In the office settling with the fencers.’

Comment: In the US I think even a lone individual operating out of the back of his minivan would call himself a "fencing contractor".

Answer (score 3):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fencer)  has *fencer* for this meaning but says mainly Australia/New Zealand. I've heard it in the UK as well.

While this is a less common use than sword fighting for sport you could use it in a list of building and related trades, for example.

Comment: Yes, the word *fencer* is used in the UK for a lone bloke who puts up a fence. If it were a company or a business you would call them *fencing contractors*.

Comment: In much of the US a "fencer" is a device that electrifies the fence.

Comment: @HotLicks that wasn't in any dictionary I saw - but the first couple of sites were being too slow for me, hence Collins, which is UK then commonwealth biased.

Answer (score 0):

It's called **fancy**, just kidding

it's usually called:

> Fence builder

A carpenter can build a fence too, well, if it's made of wood, of course, anything related to woodworking can be done by a carpenter.